# Working with mysql date range

Tags: mysql

I am attempting to retrieve records from a mysql database based on a specific date range using the following query:

```
 $query = "SELECT * FROM data WHERE" .
          "date between '11/02/13' and '11/31/13' ";
```

The problem I'm experiencing is that this query does not discriminate based on year. Another words, it returns records for November of 2014 as well as 2013. I'm sure it has to do with my lack of knowledge when it comes to working with mysql dates so if anyone can point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What's `date`'s datatype?

Comment: date although it was originally varchar

Comment: I'm guessing the conversion messed things up. Please post some sample data that reproduce the issue.

Comment: there are only two records in the database (I'm trying to make things as easy as possible during trouble shooting) and they are 11/4/13 and 11/5/14. The problem with changing things over to date datatype is that I'll eventually be using the jquery datepicker to allow the user to select the date range they would like to search between and the jquery datepicker returns dates in mm/dd/yy format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its bad to store date as varchar but you can use [STR_TO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) to convert string to date

```
SELECT * FROM data WHERE
STR_TO_DATE(`date`,'%m/%d/%y') between '11/02/13' and '11/31/13'
```

[**STR_TO_DATE**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

Comment: yeah to be honest I would like to store date as date but I'm using the jquery date picker on the front end and it formats dates as mm/dd/yy.

Comment: Have you tried above query ? and you can change the format of datepicker also see demo http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-formats

Comment: I did and I got no results found

Comment: I'm going to try changing the date format of datepicker...thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you'll have to cast the date strings to a DATE:

```
CAST('2003-01-01' AS DATE)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM data WHERE
          date between '11/02/13' and '11/31/13' GROUP BY YEAR(date)
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL you need to use different date format.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM data WHERE" .  "date between '2013-11-02' and '2013-11-31' ";
```

Answer (score 0):

The conversion of the `date` field from a varchar to a date, as stated in your comment, lead to misinterpretation of date values by MySQL, [as this fiddle proves](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8933c/2).

In order to properly convert it to a date field, you should switch it back to varchar and then do:

```
update data set date=date_format(STR_TO_DATE(`date`,'%m/%d/%y'),'%Y-%d-%m')
```

*Then* you can convert it to a date datatype, and MySQL will interprete the values correctly.

From then on, use the following syntax for checking date ranges:

```
SELECT * FROM data WHERE date between '2013-02-11' and '2013-31-11'
```

As for the comments about other frameworks accessing your data, note that the database should store everything the proper way, using proper datatypes. Client applications should adjust the way they run queries against the database, *and not the other way around*.